# My application is not parsing the JSON response

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

when i try to parse the JSON response, i got an empty response and this error:

```
JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo=0x797c420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of string}"
)
```

This is how i try to send the JSON request and how i tried to parse its response:

send the JSON request:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //Specify the adress of the webservice (url)
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/webservices/"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *jsonStringArray=[aMutableArray JSONRepresentation];

    NSLog(@"-------------");
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonStringArray);
    NSLog(@"-------------");
    [request setPostValue:jsonStringArray forKey:@"liste_des_themes"];
    NSLog(@"The response string is: %@",request.responseString);
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

For the `NSLog` where i tried to display the json string before sending it i got a correct JSON format:

```
NSLog(@"%@",jsonStringArray);//["Mairie","Préfectures et sous-préfectures"]
```

Now for the second `NSLog`, i got null:

```
NSLog(@"The response string is: %@",request.responseString);//The response string is: (null)
```

When parsing the response:

```
    -(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {   
        if(request.responseStatusCode==200)
        {   
         NSLog(@"This block gets called, response code is 200");//This block gets called, response code is 200
        //parse the response
            NSLog(@"The response string is: %@",request.responseString);

            NSString *responseString=[request responseString];
            NSDictionary *responseDict=[responseString JSONValue];
    }
}
```

For the `NSLog` trying to display the response string, i got nothing, neither null, nor a correct value:

```
         NSLog(@"The response string is: %@",request.responseString);
    //The response string is:
```

And after that, i got this trace error:

```
    JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
        "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo=0x797c420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of string}"
    )
```

Can you help me there? thanx in advance.

Comment: For me it looks like a server side problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume  you have no control over the web service, so telling you to do something about that is generally a non-starter.

1) First, make sure that the JSON response looks correct. Can you download it into a browser and see that it looks okay?

2) If it looks okay, can it pass a JSON lint test? (Try jsonlint.com, and plug it in there.)

3) If it passes (1) and (2), then see if it has any leading nulls in the returned data response. I found this to be the case in my own code. I could not work directly with this without first removing the leading nulls.

Unfortunately, I'm not at my mac to copy the code I use to solved this problem. But it was a real problem, and the solution is to remove the nulls (There were thousands of them in my case.)  Nulls in a sting look like the string terminator, so leading nulls hide the real content.

Comment: Hello Jim, i have all the control on the webservice side, it's mine, the JSON response is ok, i have already tested it on the `jsonlint.com`, however, it still the step 3 in your reply, i don't understand exactly what you mean by a leading nulls?, here is my response: `{"themes":[["Direction des Routes Secteur de Pithiviers ","mairies","Morailles 45300 PITHIVIERS LE VIEIL ","0238345744","48.823042","2.365907"],["Cr\u00e9dit Mutuel Du Centre ","banques","agence de Pithiviers  33 r Am Gourdon 45300 PITHIVIERS","0820834080","48.703042","2.145907"]]}`

Comment: For some reason, the server I was using prepended leading bytes with value 0x00. There were a lot of them. I had no control over what was being sent. It looked perfect in a browser, so I assume the browser stripped these nulls out. But when I examined the raw data that my program received, the zeros were evident, and being interpreted as null terminators of a string. Examine the raw data that is received by your url connection inside your code.

Comment: So, the zeros on the response string might be causing the problem?

Comment: Examine the raw data that is received by your url connection inside your code. Verify that it is identical to the JSON you posted above.

Comment: What you mean by raw data received by the url connection?

Comment: I just realized that you are using ASIHTTPRequest, so the configuration is slightly different than I imagined. I am not that familiar with ASIHTTPRequest, but I took a look at the source code. First, if the contents returned by `request.responseString` looks like valid JSON to you (use your console debugger to examine it), then you don't need to look at the response data. If the contents of you `request.responseString` don't look correct, you can look at `request.responseData` to see the raw data. Bonne chance!

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the web service that serves up the JSON.  Debug that and you will find the problem.